# Help with variables in htaccess redirects

Tags: .htaccess

i want to do this, redirect:

http://**anySubdomain(wildcard)**.mydomain.com/

to

**anysubdomain(wildcard)**.mydomain.com/page2.php

i tried with this:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/$1\.mydomain\.com\/page2\.php" [R=301,L]
```

But it does not work, the rewriteCond part works well, because, ANY subdomain is redirected.

But it reaches:  " .mydomain.com/page2.php"

Can you help me? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your Rewrite:

1. The [OR] is making it apply to everything
2. You don't need to escape so many chars on the Rule.
3. Need to pass through the hostname variable using %1
4. It'll create an infinite loop, as it'll also try redirecting page2.php back to itself.

This **should** do it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.*page2.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.mydomain.com/page2.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you almost got it, what you did makes ALL pages within domain.com to be redirected to page2.php. But i wanted only the root to be redirected: i took your code and changed just one thing and it did the trick:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.*page2.php$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%1.mydomain.com/page2.php [R=301,L]

^/?$